Google Sheet and will determine the start of Serial Number
I'm working on a serial number in google sheet. For every unique name, I will determine the starting number.
here's the output  that i want

here's what i did
=Arrayformula(IF(E2:E="",,LEFT(E2:E,2)) & IF(D2:D="",,YEAR(D2:D) &  "-" &TEXT(MONTH(D2:D),"0")))
and the result

Sorry for my bad english.

Try this out in B2:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2:E,UPPER(LEFT(F2:F,2))&"-"&TEXT(E2:E,"yyyy-mm")&"-"&
   TEXT(VLOOKUP(F2:F,H2:I,2,0)+COUNTIFS(F2:F,F2:F,ROW(F2:F),"<="&ROW(F2:F))-1,"000"),))


